# GroupBY frequency counts JSON response - nested field

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying aggregate the response from an API call that returns a JSON object and get some frequency counts.

I've managed to do it for one of the fields in the JSON response, but a second field that I want to try the same thing isn't working

Both fields are called "category" but the one that isn't working is nested within "outcome_status".

The error I get is KeyError: 'category'

The below code uses a public API that does not require authentication, so can be tested easily.

```
import simplejson
import requests

#make a polygon for use in the API call
lat_coord = 51.767538
long_coord = -1.497488
lat_upper = str(lat_coord + 0.02)
lat_lower = str(lat_coord - 0.02)
long_upper = str(long_coord + 0.02)
long_lower = str(long_coord - 0.02)

#call from the API - no authentication required
api_call="https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=" + lat_lower + "," + long_upper + ":" + lat_lower  + "," + long_lower + ":" + lat_upper + "," + long_lower + ":"  + lat_upper  + "," + long_upper + "&date=2017-01"
print (api_call)

request_resp=requests.get(api_call).json()

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_resp = pd.DataFrame(request_resp)

#frequency counts for non-nested field (this works) 
df_resp.groupby('category').context.count()

#next bit tries to do the nested (this doesn't work)

#tried dropping nulls
df_outcome = df_resp['outcome_status'].dropna()
print(df_outcome)

#tried index reset
df_outcome.reset_index()

#just errors
df_outcome.groupby('category').date.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have the easiest time of it, if you expand the dict in the `"outcome_status"` column like:

#### Code:

```
outcome_status = [
    {'outcome_status_' + k: v for k, v in z.items()} for z in (
        dict(category=None, date=None) if x is None else x
        for x in (y['outcome_status'] for y in request_resp)
    )
]
df = pd.concat([df_resp.drop('outcome_status', axis=1),
                pd.DataFrame(outcome_status)], axis=1)
```

This uses some comprehensions to rename the fields in the `outcome_status` by pre-pending `"outcome_status_"` to the key names and turning them into columns. It also expands `None` values as well.

#### Test Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

# make a polygon for use in the API call
lat_coord = 51.767538
long_coord = -1.497488
lat_upper = str(lat_coord + 0.02)
lat_lower = str(lat_coord - 0.02)
long_upper = str(long_coord + 0.02)
long_lower = str(long_coord - 0.02)

# call from the API - no authentication required
api_call = ("https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=" +
            lat_lower + "," + long_upper + ":" +
            lat_lower + "," + long_lower + ":" +
            lat_upper + "," + long_lower + ":" +
            lat_upper + "," + long_upper + "&date=2017-01")

request_resp = requests.get(api_call).json()
df_resp = pd.DataFrame(request_resp)

outcome_status = [
    {'outcome_status_' + k: v for k, v in z.items()} for z in (
        dict(category=None, date=None) if x is None else x
        for x in (y['outcome_status'] for y in request_resp)
    )
]
df = pd.concat([df_resp.drop('outcome_status', axis=1),
                pd.DataFrame(outcome_status)], axis=1)

# just errors
print(df.groupby('outcome_status_category').category.count())
```

#### Results:

```
outcome_status_category
Court result unavailable                          4
Investigation complete; no suspect identified    38
Local resolution                                  1
Offender given a caution                          2
Offender given community sentence                 3
Offender given conditional discharge              1
Offender given penalty notice                     2
Status update unavailable                         6
Suspect charged as part of another case           1
Unable to prosecute suspect                       9
Name: category, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks. I see what the code has done there, but I'd never have come up with that in a million years. If I want to read up on that I should be reading about comprehensions. Right?

Comment: Yes, Comprehensions.

Comment: I REALLY like that. I did this to return a count the 18 nulls with a description of "Empty"

outcome_status = [
    {'outcome_status_' + k: v for k, v in z.items()} for z in (
        dict(category='Empty', date='Empty') if x is None else x
        for x in (y['outcome_status'] for y in request_resp)
    )
]